# Button disappears after several click

Tags: javascript, html

I really struggling with doing the same thing in infinite try.

I'm trying to add same functionality to similar element using Foreach on the parent element.

everything went well until I hit the buttons several times, it just disappear.

I think the problem is in the loop, I welcome any kink of comments.

```js
const containerDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.box.center');
containerDivs.forEach(containerDiv => {
    const leftContainer = containerDiv.querySelector('.left_container');
    const arrow = containerDiv.querySelector('.arr_container');
    const cancel =  containerDiv.querySelector('.cancel');

    arrow.addEventListener("click", ({ target: arrow }) => {
        arrow.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("off")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("off");
            leftContainer.classList.add("active");
        }

    });

    cancel.addEventListener("click", ({ target: cancel }) => {
        cancel.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("active")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("active");
            leftContainer.classList.add("off")
        }

    });
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c5346, #203a43, #0f2027);
}

.center{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main{
    height: 100vh;
}

.box{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px; 
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.288);
    border-radius: 23px;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}

}
/*arrow*/
.arr_container .cancel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.arr_container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.arr_container i{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.active_arr{
    transform: translate(80%, 80%);
}
.left_container{
    position: absolute;
    background: #0f2027;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 23px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 20px;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.off{
    transform: translate(-80%,-80%) rotate(90deg);
}
.active{
    transform: translate(0) rotate(0);
}

.left_container .icons{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.left_container .icons i{
    color: #cfcfcf;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.left_container .icons i:hover{
    color: #2c5346;
}
.cancel{
        right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
}
.cancel .fas{
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cards.css">
    <title>cards</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main center">
    <div class="box center">
        <div>
            <p class="user_name">Mor Maz</p>
        </div>
        <div class="arr_container center">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="left_container off">
            <p>Skill</p>
            <div class="cancel">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box center">
        <div>
            <p class="user_name">Mor Maz</p>
        </div>
        <div class="arr_container center">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="left_container off">
            <p>Skill</p>
            
            
            <div class="cancel">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="cards.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate any kind of help

thank you

Comment: Your event listeners add the class `active-arr` but it seems like you never remove it; is that correct? Also, the button does not "just disappear", it keeps changing its position (because of the CSS `translate()`, I assume), until it eventually ends up out of the visible area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it out and found that the active_arr class the the one that is causing the problem, the buttons are not disappearing but just moving outside the boundary of the parent container which has a overflow: hidden; property. You are forgetting to remove the arctive_arr class from the opposite button do as follows and it will work

```
const containerDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.box.center');
    containerDivs.forEach(containerDiv => {
        const leftContainer = containerDiv.querySelector('.left_container');
        const arrow = containerDiv.querySelector('.arr_container');
        const cancel =  containerDiv.querySelector('.cancel');

    arrow.addEventListener("click", ({ target: arrow }) => {
        arrow.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("off")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("off");
            leftContainer.classList.add("active");
        }
        cancel.classList.remove("active_arr");

    });

    cancel.addEventListener("click", ({ target: cancel }) => {
        cancel.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("active")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("active");
            leftContainer.classList.add("off")
        }
        arrow.classList.remove("active_arr");

    });
});
```

Tho there is still a padding issue I can see you can fix it on your own

Answer (score 0):

You are adding "active_arr" but you never remove it.

Your css are hiding the buttons then:

```
.active_arr {
   transform: translate(80%, 80%);
}
```